# WorldWind Layer manager panel is blank

Tags: java, swing, worldwind

I am developing a WorldWind application and I want to reuse the LayerAndElevationManagerPanel example class in my own application. I am trying to put it into a dialog box that the user can pull up on demand, however when the dialog is displayed the scroll pane for the panel is empty. Can this example be reused?

Here is the example code from WorldWind

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 United States Government as represented by the Administrator of the
 * National Aeronautics and Space Administration.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 */

package gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.layermanager;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindow;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Combines the layer manager and elevation model manager in a single frame.
 *
 * @author tag
 * @version $Id$
 */
public class LayerAndElevationManagerPanel extends JPanel
{
    protected LayerManagerPanel layerManagerPanel;
    protected ElevationModelManagerPanel elevationModelManagerPanel;

    public LayerAndElevationManagerPanel(WorldWindow wwd)
    {
        super(new BorderLayout(10, 10));

        this.add(this.layerManagerPanel = new LayerManagerPanel(wwd), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.add(this.elevationModelManagerPanel = new ElevationModelManagerPanel(wwd), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void updateLayers(WorldWindow wwd)
    {
        this.layerManagerPanel.update(wwd);
    }

    public void updateElevations(WorldWindow wwd)
    {
        this.elevationModelManagerPanel.update(wwd);
    }

    public void update(WorldWindow wwd)
    {
        this.updateLayers(wwd);
        this.updateElevations(wwd);
    }
}
```

Here is my code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import gov.nasa.worldwind.WorldWindow;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.layermanager.LayerAndElevationManagerPanel;

public class LayerDialog extends JDialog
{

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public LayerDialog(WorldWindow wwd)
    {
        setTitle("Layer Manager");
        setBounds(100, 100, 386, 360);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(null);
        scrollPane.add(new LayerAndElevationManagerPanel(wwd));
        GroupLayout gl_contentPanel = new GroupLayout(contentPanel);
        gl_contentPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 344, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(6, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPanel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPanel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(scrollPane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 257, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        contentPanel.setLayout(gl_contentPanel);
        {
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
            buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            {
                JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
                okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
                buttonPane.add(okButton);
                getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
            }
            {
                JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
                cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
                buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is an excerpt from MainWindow

```
    public MainWindow(App a)
    {

       WorldWindowGLCanvas wwd = new WorldWindowGLCanvas();

       JMenuItem mntmLayers = new JMenuItem("Layers");
       mntmLayers.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {
           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
               try
               {
                   LayerDialog dialog = new LayerDialog(wwd);
                   dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                   dialog.setVisible(true);
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
    }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: How do you show your Dialog-window since there is no `main`-method here? Also might the `WorldWindow wwd` be null, when you input it as a parameter? The 6 `{ }` brackets before the last 2 brackets are useless and confusing, you should remove them

Comment: @hamena314 Added code for instantiation. Apologies on the braces. That is the code that is generated from WindowBuilder.

Comment: No problem, Eclipse and such will just ignore the brackets. They were just confusing in the beginning. When `actionPerformed()` is called, a new `LayerDialog dialog = new LayerDialog(wwd);` gets created. Might it be, that the `wwd` is null / empty? Could you show, where you create `WorldWindow wwd`?

Comment: `WorldWindow` is the application-level object that WorldWind uses. It holds much of the application's data. Suffice to say, if WorldWind is null we will have much bigger problems on our hands. Let's assume `wwd != null`. A `WorldWindow` instance is created and the startup of my application and is passed to the `MainWindow` of my application, who when triggered, passes it to `LayerDialog`. In this case, LayerAndElevationManager uses `wwd` to display all of the globe layers and allow the user to select which ones he/she wants to enable.

Comment: Yes, but since `LayerAndElevationManagerPanel` uses `wwd` as a parameter and your dialog is empty, you can not assume that `wwd != null`. You definitely should check that without assuming. :) ... it **still** would be very helpful to see, where the `wwd` in `LayerDialog dialog = new LayerDialog(wwd);` get's created. There must be some line like `WorldWindow wwd = new WorldWindow;` or something.

Comment: Yes. I have the line `WorldWindow wwd = new WorldWindow;` in my MainWindow code. However if `wwd` was null in this case, then wouldn't I have had a NullPointerException when code tries to access it? I realize that none of the code I have posted tries to dereference `wwd` but I have checked and `LayerManagerPanel` in `LayerAndElevationManager` does dereference it and does not check for null beforehand. I would post more code, but this is getting too far into the weeds. I wanted to focus on if I am structuring the Panels and Panes correctly or if there is something else I totally glossed over.

Comment: @hamena314 Its's a fair point though. I will grant you that.